# Ant javac classpathref not working?

Tags: ant, classpath, javac, apache-commons-io

The `javac` task in my `compile` target fails despite the required jars being on the classpath. Could anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

The error below is caused because `IOUtils.lineIterator()` is not recognized. However, **commons-io-1.3.1.jar** is on the build path (in `${app.lib.dir}`). So, it's strange that the build fails.

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true" classpathref="dependency.path"
        excludes="/../security/**" >
        <src path="${java.src.dir}" />
    </javac>
</target>

<path id="dependency.path">
    <fileset dir="${spring.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${spring.depends.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${app.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${tomcat.dir}/.." includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>
```

#### Execution

```
ant -f build-dev.xml compile

Buildfile: C:\..\build-dev.xml compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\..\classes
    [javac] Compiling 348 source files to C:\..\classes
    [javac] C:\..\UploadUtil.java:132: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method lineIterator(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    [javac]             Iterator<String> it = IOUtils.lineIterator(is, charSet);
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
C:\..\build-dev.xml:54: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 11 seconds
```

#### Approaches tried

1. **Eclipse**, surprisingly, is building the project without any problem. I have the same set of jars on the project build path. I also have the same source directory excluded from the compilation.
2. Attempted to use **javac** executable on the source folder, but not sure how to use javac on a source-code directory structure.
3. I'm sure the version of the jar I have has the class `IOUtils` because Eclipse shows it in the contents of the jar.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely explanation is that the jar containing the class is not on the classpath.

I double-checked Maven Central, just in case there was a jar called "commons-io-1.3.1" that does not contain this class, but sadly no:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22commons-io%22%20AND%20NOT%20fc%3A%22org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils%22

So I'd suggest is that you add the following diagnostic target into your build so that you can confirm that the jar is in fact on the classpath:

```
<target name="diagnostics">
    <pathconvert property="classpathProp" refid="dependency.path"/>

    <echo>Classpath is ${classpathProp}</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: The **jar is on the classpath** (was displayed by the above target). However, there were 5 instances of the jar fetched from various locations. I changed it to keep only 1 instance on the classpath. But, the compile still fails. I'm sure the version of the jar I have has the class `IOUtils` because Eclipse shows it in the contents of the jar.